# Switch MTA-STS from testing to enforce without receiving any reports

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

I've added MTA-STS to our email. The MX records are correct and are accepted. This is also confirmed by MTA-STS checks with e.g. mxtoolbox.com

Our TXT file can be reached by https://mta-sts.domain.com/.well-known/mta-sts.txt

As we are using Office365 email the content of the textfile is:
version: STSv1
mode: testing
mx: *.mail.protection.outlook.com
max_age: 86401

In the last 3 weeks I didn't received any report from a sending provider. Although I added my emailaddress to the TXT record I've added in our DNS.
v=TLSRPTv1;rua=mailto:webmaster@domain.com

Is this normal and does it mean it's all good? Can I safely switch to enforce mode now, without having the risk that incoming email is getting blocked?